# Open href="#tab-something via URL

Tags: tabs

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
<a href="#tab-description"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a>
<a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
<a href="#tab-review"><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a>
<a href="#tab-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>
</div>
```

When I click this link, for example: `.../product_id=40` by default the `#tab-description` is opened. How can I call `#tab-review` via URL to be opened first, i.e. if I enter the URL to be something like this: `.../product_id=40#tab-review` the `#tab-review` to be opened?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the tabs.js content, and the path to this file is: .../catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js

```
$.fn.tabs = function() {
var selector = this;

this.each(function() {
    var obj = $(this); 

    $(obj.attr('href')).hide();

    $(obj).click(function() {
        $(selector).removeClass('selected');

        $(selector).each(function(i, element) {
            $($(element).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        $(this).addClass('selected');

        $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });
});

$(this).show();

$(this).first().click();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? You could put this in a `ready` listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash.length > 1) {
        $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
    }
});
```

If you're *not* using jQuery, I'll need some more information...

Comment: Nope, not using jQuery... Here you go the complete file: https://rapidshare.com/files/2018237947/product.zip

Comment: UPDATE: I actually use jQuery, sorry, didn't realize that the script does. So, any chance you could edit your code the way I can just copy/paste into my file? I also edited my first post, added the tabs.js content.

Comment: @NikolaNastevski: Okay! It's now just drop-in. Put it in any script file or tag.

Comment: Oooooo niceee, and this actually scrolls down to the #tab-something, huh? Tnx dude, you da man :) I put it between <script></script> tags, hope it's ok, because it's working :) Once again, THANK you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 <script>
 //--edit add check if having a hash
 if (location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
    if(window.location.hash) {
       //get hash value and put to a variable
       var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
       alert (hash);
       // hash found add selected class to the tab
    } else {
       // No hash found
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: I just pasted it above the code I wrote, but nothing happens... Any ideas?

Comment: @NikolaNastevski: You have to implement some things. wargodz009: You don't need to check for `location.href.indexOf("#") != -1` *and* `window.location.hash` - if the hash doesn't exist, it will be an empty string, and that's a falsy value.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what to implement, to be honest :) If you can tell me the exact code that I should put, it would be extremely helpful. You can also download the full file I uploaded on rapidshare, and posted the link in your answer's comments.

Comment: the file you attached is not enough. its just template. but from my experience about tabs i know that for a specific tab to show you just need to apply a class name which tells your tab script that this tab is the current. here's an example of how to add class to an element using jquery: $('#tab-review').addClass('active'); and remove the active class for the default active tab by this code: $('#tab-description').removeClass('active');

Comment: Tnx, I'll try, but I'll also wait for minitech's answer to see if he can come up with something.